# MySQL - order by and leading zeroes

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of products in my database with imaginative names like '256', '167 brown' and '1115 black'
I need to return them ordered by product number so that product named 256 would come before 1115 black but after 167 brown.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT code FROM your_table
ORDER BY CAST(code AS SIGNED)
```

Comment: +1 I didn't think this would work because of the trailing non-numeric characters, but it seems to ditch them correctly.

Comment: Oh, that's very clever. Works great, thanks. But just in case... let's say the product's name is something that only has letters, how would I make it list after all the numbers? (since the letters cast to 0)